# Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'model: 1777'. Current value: 'model: 2222'

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I have this html code, in this code I used [(ngModel)] for change my value input, and when I change I want to calculate automatic my Total, subtotal and Amound Paid. 
Maybe this is not good solution because I have some problem.

1. When I add some data, my all data chnage value, all get the last set value.
   Like in photo,

   [image: enter code here]

Please I need help.

My html code

```
 <form [formGroup]="addsale" (ngSubmit)="onaddsale()">
      <table align="center" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr style="color:black;">
            <th>Unit_price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of products; let i = index">
             <td>
              <input formControlName="Unit_price" id="Unit_price " type="number" class="validate"[(ngModel)]="item.Unit_price">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input formControlName="Quantity" id="Quantity " type="number" class="validate"  [(ngModel)]="item.Quantity"> 
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" formControlName="Description" id="Description" name="Description" [(ngModel)]="item.Description">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input formControlName="Subtotal" id="Subtotal" type="number" class="validate"  [(ngModel)]="item.Subtotal">
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="fa" (click)="onDelete(i)">x</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
          <label for="total">Total {{total}} ALL</label>
          <input formControlName="total" id="total" type="text" class="validate"   [(ngModel)]="total">
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
          <label for="amount_paid">Amount Paid:</label>
          <input formControlName="amount_paid" id="amount_paid" [(ngModel)]="total" type="text" class="validate">
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
          <label for="total">Subtotal</label>
          <input formControlName="Subtotal" id="Subtotal" type="text" class="validate"  [(ngModel)]="total">
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>
      <br>
      <div id="add_homebox_button_container" class="row" style="float: right;">
        <button id="add_client_button" type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">
          Register
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Code ts:

```
export class AddSaleFormComponent implements OnInit {
  addsale: FormGroup;
  loading: boolean = false;
  client: Client[];
  producttype: ProductType[];
  contrat: Contrat[];
  gpss: GPS[];
  homeboxp: HomeboxP[];
  sensors: Sensors[];
  homebox: Homebox[];
  products: Products[] = [];
  Price: number = 0;
  Total;
  variable: any;
  Quantity: number;
  Unit_price: number;

  selectedClient: Client = new Client('');
  @Input() selectedProduct: Products;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private ss: SalesService,
    private ps: ProductsService,
    private cs: ClientService,
    private pts: ProducttypeService,
    private css: ContratService,
    private gps: GpsService,
    private hbp: HomeboxpackageService,
    private sensor: SensorsService,
    private hb: HomeboxService

  ) {
    this.addsale = this.fb.group({
      'invoice_number': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.nullValidator]),
      'invoice_date': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'client_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'amount_paid': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'notes': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'Subtotal': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'products': this.fb.array([]),
      'total': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'contactNo': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'address': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'Unit_price': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'Quantity': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'Description': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'line_num': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.products = this.ps.getProduct();
    console.log(this.products)

    this.pts.getAllProductType().subscribe(
      producttype => {
        this.producttype = producttype;
      }
    );
  }


  onaddsale() {
    this.loading = true;
    let sale = this.addsale.value
    sale.products = this.products

    let newSale = new Sale(sale);
    console.log(newSale)

    this.ss.saleitemcreate(newSale).subscribe(
      result => {
        if (result === true) {
          Materialize.toast('Sale saved successfully', 4000);
        } else {
          this.loading = false;
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    );
  }

  get total() {
    let Total = 0;
    for (let p of this.products) {
      Total += p.Unit_price * p.Quantity;
    }
    return Total;
  }
  Subtotal() {
    let subtotal = 0;
    for (let p of this.products) {
      subtotal = p.Unit_price * p.Quantity;
    }
    console.log(subtotal)
    return subtotal;
  }

}
```

Comment: We need the code of the component. It seems you're changing the values of your properties after changing detection, and that's not good. Besides, if you're using `ngModel` you shouldn't use `[value]`, as `ngModel` already updates the form field when the data it points to changes.

Comment: @OscarPaz Please how to change my code? I edit my post. Thnx

Comment: Also, I change [value], and nothing change

Comment: @OscarPaz can you help please?

Comment: When you say 'when I add some data', what do you mean? Adding a new row? Can you add rows?

Comment: Yes, In this table products I add some data. Like in photo

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `FormGroup`. As you can see, you've got one `FormControl` for 'Unit_price'. However, in your template, you've got several rows, and in each row there is an input that points to that same `FormControl` (via the `FormControlName` directive). But they all belong to the same `FormGroup`, and that messes with the form, so all the inputs with the same name refer to the same `FormControl`, causing the odd behaviour you're suffering. You can't have duplicate controls under the same `FormGroup` directive.

What you've got to do is define a `FormGroup` for each row of the table. This way, you'll have an array of `FormGroup`. In each of them, there will be a `FormControl` with a unique name, and so your problems will disappear.

This means you've got to make a `FormGroup` for each product in the `products` array, and maybe a different `FormGroup` for the common controls (total, Subtotal...).

Of course, this means that the `products` array in the `FormGroup` no longer is necessary.

Another advice is to remove data binding from the 'total' fields, as you won't edit them. You can change [(ngModel)] to just [ngModel] for them.

In fact, though I'm not an expert in reactive forms, I think that, if you're using FormControl and FormGroup, you don't need `ngModel` at all.

Comment: Yes  I understand, but this problem show only when I used [(ngModel)]. When I use [value] this is normal, but in this I want to change my value, for example, I want to change quantity, and this moment my total and subtotal will be change automatic. Thanx for your comment