# How to update my total when I have quantity * price in typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sum, calculated-columns

In this code I implement to add sale, in one sale I have and produts, these products I has in an array Products, and display in this table. My problem is, when I add some products, my value, price, quantity and total display ok, but I can't change my total automatic when I can change quantity or price. I tired to use [(ngModel)] in [Value] I can change my total, but my value are  the same, like in photo
[image]

Edit code html

```
 <form [formGroup]="addsale" (ngSubmit)="onaddsale()">

          <tr class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of products; let i = index">
             <td>
              <input formControlName="Unit_price" id="Unit_price " type="number" class="validate"[value]="item.Unit_price">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input formControlName="Quantity" id="Quantity " type="number" class="validate"  [value]="item.Quantity"> 
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" formControlName="Description" id="Description" name="Description" [value]="item.Description">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input formControlName="Subtotal" id="Subtotal" type="number" class="validate"  [value]="item.Subtotal">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
          <label for="total">Total {{total}} ALL</label>
          <input formControlName="total" id="total" type="text" class="validate"   [value]="total">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

For `{{total}}` I call this function in ts:

Code ts:

```
        this.addsale = this.fb.group({
          'invoice_number': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.nullValidator]),
          'amount_paid': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'notes': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'Subtotal': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'products': this.fb.array([]),
          'total': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'Unit_price': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'Quantity': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          'Description': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        });
      }

      ngOnInit() {

        this.products = this.ps.getProduct();
        console.log(this.products)

        this.pts.getAllProductType().subscribe(
          producttype => {
            this.producttype = producttype;
          }
        );
      }


      onaddsale() {

      }

      get total() {
        let Total = 0;
        for (let p of this.products) {
          Total += p.Unit_price * p.Quantity;
        }
        return Total;
      }
        }
```

Can you suggest me how to implement update total when I change quantity or unie_price?

Thank you

Comment: I want to update my total when i change quantity or price

Comment: Use ngModel instead of value

Comment: Do you change via input or from the code?

Comment: I tried to use this model but when I have more than one [(ngModule)] product, I set the last product values

Comment: ok, thank you. I'm waiting

Answer (score 1):

Complete example using ngModel:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'products',
    template: `
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of products">
                <td>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="item.Unit_price" type="number">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="item.Quantity" type="number">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.Description" name="Description">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input readonly [(ngModel)]="item.Subtotal" type="number">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
            <label for="total">Total {{total}} ALL</label>
            <input type="text" [value]="total">
        </div>
    `
})
export class ProductsComponent {

    private products: any [] = [
        {
            Unit_price: 1,
            Quantity: 1,
        },
        {
            Unit_price: 1,
            Quantity: 1,
        }
    ];

    get total() {
        return this.products
            .map(p => p.Unit_price * p.Quantity)
            .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: <label for="total">Total {{total}} ALL</label>  this call the get method total

Comment: Oops I didn't notice you used a getter. If you implement a real method it should works.

Comment: My total  does not change when I change the amount of quantity

Comment: Yep sorry, i missunderstood your issue. Edited to show a complete example. But if you have to use ReactiveForm i could edit this answer.

Comment: You must to implement formArrayName to handle your array of products. Then you must listen to your form group values and not the initial `products` array.

Answer (score 1):

Use two-way binding to update your model value, so total would be updated accordingly. Also remove formControlName as it is for reactive forms.

**HTML**

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of products; let i = index">
        <td>
            <input id="Unit_price " type="number" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="item.Unit_price">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="Quantity " type="number" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="item.Quantity">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="Description" name="Description" [(ngModel)]="item.Description">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input readonly id="Subtotal" type="number" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="item.Subtotal">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
    <label for="total">Total {{total}} ALL</label>
    <input id="total" type="text" class="validate" [value]="total">
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-embkvx)

Comment: I tried to use like this, but show me this error, like in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319466/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-previous-value-model-1777-curr Thank you